# Xaxis data given to highcharts in descending order but still xaxis appears in ascending order

Tags: javascript, sorting, highcharts, time-series

I want to plot timeseries with descending sort on xaxis data. I have given my data in descending order but still highcharts plot it in ascending order
check fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/r4rex6oz/

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
xAxis: {
    type: 'datetime'
},
series: [{
    data: [
        [Date.UTC(2010, 0, 8), 176.0],
        [Date.UTC(2010, 0, 7), 144.0],
        [Date.UTC(2010, 0, 6), 129.2],
        [Date.UTC(2010, 0, 3), 106.4],
        [Date.UTC(2010, 0, 2), 71.5],
        [Date.UTC(2010, 0, 1), 29.9]
    ]
}]
```

});

Comment: You can place your data in descending order - you are receiving the error in the console because of unsorted data. You need to put your data in ascending order and set xaxis.reversed to true - http://jsfiddle.net/r4rex6oz/3/

Comment: @Purva a small question, What is that you want to convey exactly in this graph by showing the reverse time series? because most often people read things from left to right and there is more chances that they may ignore the fact that the x axis is reversed and end up drawing wrong insights.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can reverse by adding `reversed: true`.

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
xAxis: {
    type: 'datetime',
    reversed: true
},
series: [{
    data: [
        [Date.UTC(2010, 0, 8), 176.0],
        [Date.UTC(2010, 0, 7), 144.0],
        [Date.UTC(2010, 0, 6), 129.2],
        [Date.UTC(2010, 0, 3), 106.4],
        [Date.UTC(2010, 0, 2), 71.5],
        [Date.UTC(2010, 0, 1), 29.9]
    ]
  }]
});
```

Check out more options [here](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.reversed).